# Как сделать тень только с одной стороны?

Tags: css, css3

Хочу сделать тень у `div` блока, но чтобы она была только с одной стороны - сверху.

Исходный стиль:

```css
div {
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что тень присутствует так же и слева и справа (совсем капельку и снизу, что тоже является недопустимым). Различные манипуляции с 2-4 значениями ни к чему не привели (да и позиционирование хочется сохранить текущее). Тень так или иначе все равно присутствует по бокам.

Как все же добиться желаемого результата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем случае получилось обыграть ситуацию с помощью внутренней тени:

```css
div {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -7px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);/* получившаяся тень */
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

По сути раннее внешнее позиционирование на топ'е блока ушло на внутреннее нижнее позиционирование соседнего блока. В результате все выглядит достаточно чисто.

Также, пока писал этот ответ, в голову пришла альтернативная идея по внутренней реализации в соседнем блоке - это с помощью `linear-gradient`.

Answer (score 3):

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<section><div></div></section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Хотел сделать тень только сверху и только внутрь. Свойством box-shadow ничего не вышло этим, зато с фоном получилось:

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Это у вас ответ или вопрос?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ответ это. Добавил сниппет.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сверху, нужун `box-shadow: 0 -6px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);`

```css
div {
  box-shadow: 0 -6px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Вы скопировали предыдущий ответ? :) Не зря же его автор удалил.

Comment: нужно -6px а не  6px. хотел комментировать, но удалили и получился ответ.

Comment: Я умею копировать код и вставлять его в редактор. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на мой образец, а затем на ваш. Есть только одно сходство без учета alpha-канала - это цвет. Как я уже писал - с позиционированием я уже игрался.

Comment: а скиньте все правило css для вашего div

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich Вот оно: `box-shadow: 0 -6px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)`. Ну еще правда есть это: `background-color: #fff; padding: 1.5rem;`. Ничего криминального.

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich мне-то по сути надо удалить тень с боков, сохранив то что сверху (сохранив размер, а то не все это почему-то понимают...)

Comment: а вот так? box-shadow: 0px -26px 42px -23px #000000;

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich неа. Тоже как-то стремно выглядит. Я написал свой ответ, где решил проблему немного другим подходом.

Comment: ну ок. хорошо что разобрались.